# Stretching <a> tag to fill parent <li> in horizontal list

Tags: css, html-lists, drupal-theming

Here's my (abstracted) css and HTML:

```
#primary-menu{
text-align: center;
margin: 20px 0;
}

#primary-menu li{
list-style-type:none;
display: inline;
margin: 8px;
padding: 5px 30px;
}

#primary-menu ul{
padding: 20px 0px;
}

<div id="primary-menu">
<ul id="main-menu">
<li><a href="one">one</a></li>
<li><a href="two">two</a></li>
<li><a href="three">three</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

I've tried putting `#primary-menu a{display:block;}` and taking out `display: inline;` and adding in `float:left;` in `#primary-menu li` but then the list shifts down the page and moves outside of the containing div, plus it doesn't seem like it keeps the `<a>` streached after I put `float:left;` in.

Another option I know of would be to change the list to look like `<a href="one"><li>one</li></a>` but I wouldn't really want to do this because (apart from it feeling very hacky) this list is being created by Drupal and I wouldn't really know how to do this without having to learning how the API works, which doesn't seem worth it for this one problem.

All help would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely sure what it is you want to achieve, but is this fiddle along the right lines? http://jsfiddle.net/eaJhv/1/  I've added in borders and colours to make it more obvious what's where.

Comment: Did the same thing, http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/4GRv2/

Comment: Your question title says "vertical list", but your CSS has the list elements displayed horizontally. Can you clarify the effect you're attempting to achieve?

Comment: Apologies. I meant horizontal, it was the end of a long day (which is probably why I had the issue in the first place) and some how I managed to muddle up vertical and horizontal, I've edited it now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I get it right, then you just have to remove the padding from the li element and add it to the a. Also you have to change the display type:

```
#primary-menu li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
}

#primary-menu li a {
   padding: 5px 30px;
   display:block;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/v6ZFx/

Comment: Thanks. I think I had been looking at it too much and was way overcomplicating things, couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

ids should be unique. use classes instead.
never place a block element in an inline element.
li { display: inline-block; width: auto; padding: 0}

Now you can set the width of a_s to the full size. Or set the width on the li elements.